# IBMQ / Qiskit slack links are broken

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

It appears the Slack links to IBMQ slack pages are broken (The link is no longer active). This is case for links on both Qiskit and IBMQ support pages.

What is the best way to gain access to the Slack group?

Thank you.

Link to IBMQ support page: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/support

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic here

Comment: I've just checked the link and it works for me... Maybe it was just a bug that they fixed? In any case, I've mentioned it in their Slack Channel

Answer (score 2):

This link was shared in the Qiskit Global Summer School Discord channel.

[https://join.slack.com/t/qiskit/shared_invite/zt-fybmq791-hYRopcSH6YetxycNPXgv~A](https://join.slack.com/t/qiskit/shared_invite/zt-fybmq791-hYRopcSH6YetxycNPXgv%7EA)

I hope this works for you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider https://ibm.co/joinqiskitslack the Slack link, it's always updated to a working invitation link.

Comment: Does not work anymore :(